# iOS + gtm-oauth2 library: Getting a 401 invalid request

Tags: ios, objective-c, ruby-on-rails, oauth

I have a Ruby on Rails application which is an OAuth 2.0 provider thanks to the Doorkeeper gem and has an API. I am building an iPhone client that will interact with the API; it uses the gtm-oauth2 library for the authentication process.

I finished the OAuth authentication part, so a user can add an account to the iPhone app. Now I need to retrieve the authorization from the iPhone (or iPhone Simulator) keychain to interact with the private API of my main application. Here is the code that I have:

```
GTMOAuth2Authentication *auth = [_db catapultAuthenticaiton];
[GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch authorizeFromKeychainForName:kCatapultKeychainItemName
                                            authentication:auth];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.lvh.me:3000/api/clients/%@", accountName]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
GTMHTTPFetcher *fetcher = [GTMHTTPFetcher fetcherWithRequest:request];
[fetcher setAuthorizer:auth];
[fetcher beginFetchWithCompletionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
#if DEBUG
        NSLog(@"Error fetching client: %@", error);
#endif
    }
}];
```

In the fetcher completion handler I am getting a 401 invalid_request error when trying to retrieve an existing authorization from the keychain and doing an API call to the server:

```
2013-04-02 11:08:55.546 Catapult for iOS[31776:c07] Error Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)" UserInfo=0x7248010 {data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a22696e 76616c69 645f7265 71756573 74222c22 6572726f 725f6465 73637269 7074696f 6e223a22 54686520 72657175 65737420 6973206d 69737369 6e672061 20726571 75697265 64207061 72616d65 7465722c 20696e63 6c756465 7320616e 20756e73 7570706f 72746564 20706172 616d6574 65722076 616c7565 2c206f72 20697320 6f746865 72776973 65206d61 6c666f72 6d65642e 227d>}
Error data:
{
    error = "invalid_request";
    "error_description" = "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.";
}
2013-04-02 11:08:55.546 Catapult for iOS[31776:c07] Error fetching client: Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=401 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.google.HTTPStatus error 401.)" UserInfo=0x725bf00 {data=<7b226572 726f7222 3a22696e 76616c69 645f7265 71756573 74222c22 6572726f 725f6465 73637269 7074696f 6e223a22 54686520 72657175 65737420 6973206d 69737369 6e672061 20726571 75697265 64207061 72616d65 7465722c 20696e63 6c756465 7320616e 20756e73 7570706f 72746564 20706172 616d6574 65722076 616c7565 2c206f72 20697320 6f746865 72776973 65206d61 6c666f72 6d65642e 227d>, json={
    error = "invalid_request";
    "error_description" = "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.";
}}
```

I used GTMHTTPFetcherLogging to log the HTTP request made and here is what was logged:

```
refresh token for oauth.lvh.me

2013-04-02 10:08:55 +0000
Request: POST https://oauth.lvh.me:3000/oauth/token
Request headers:
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
  User-Agent: gtm-oauth2 com.catapult.Catapult-for-iOS/1.0

Request body: (257 bytes)
client_id=b29a572c2caa218b8591011e1cc67f0f3536ffe4c449ab7b806dd4d363681401&client_secret=_snip_&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=_snip_

Response: status 401
Response headers:
  Cache-Control: no-store
  Connection: close
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Pragma: no-cache
  Server: thin 1.5.1 codename Straight Razor
  Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
  X-Request-Id: 65b11f0a4fc06fa5562332252fd6cdcd
  X-Runtime: 0.212716
  X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge

Response body: (162 bytes)
{
  "error_description" : "The request is missing a required parameter, includes an unsupported parameter value, or is otherwise malformed.",
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

And here are the server's logs:

```
Started POST "/oauth/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-02 11:08:55 +0100
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "oauth_access_tokens".* FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE "oauth_access_tokens"."refresh_token" = 'ddb0a1bd3256e351ff7081300dc7ac73035e897ea93d36053b7fb87843015a51' LIMIT 1
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = 'b29a572c2caa218b8591011e1cc67f0f3536ffe4c449ab7b806dd4d363681401' AND "oauth_applications"."secret" = 'b0de316c20112708d04284f6867f5bb51c1d20c72415642b38f09a8faca966cd' LIMIT 1
```

When the request works, here is how the  server's logs look like:

```
Started POST "/oauth/token" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-02 11:19:19 +0100
  Doorkeeper::AccessGrant Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "oauth_access_grants".* FROM "oauth_access_grants" WHERE "oauth_access_grants"."token" = '4391e187a0df16c56d1e6b16bf51340af8d677dbf625c495f50a249678e0502e' LIMIT 1
  Doorkeeper::Application Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "oauth_applications".* FROM "oauth_applications" WHERE "oauth_applications"."uid" = 'b29a572c2caa218b8591011e1cc67f0f3536ffe4c449ab7b806dd4d363681401' AND "oauth_applications"."secret" = 'b0de316c20112708d04284f6867f5bb51c1d20c72415642b38f09a8faca966cd' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.0ms)  UPDATE "oauth_access_grants" SET "revoked_at" = '2013-04-02 10:19:19' WHERE "oauth_access_grants"."id" = 7
  Doorkeeper::AccessToken Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "oauth_access_tokens".* FROM "oauth_access_tokens" WHERE "oauth_access_tokens"."application_id" = 1 AND "oauth_access_tokens"."resource_owner_id" = 266 AND "oauth_access_tokens"."revoked_at" IS NULL ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1
```

So there is clearly something wrong here... I don't know if the problem comes from the server or the iOS client, but my guts tell me it comes from the client.

Any clues on what is happening please?

Comment: Your code does not give enough insight. My guess is that you have an access-grant which you need to trade in for a token and you are actually trying to trade it in as a refresh-token.